# Datetimepicker did not work with SQL parameters and work with directly like SQL injection

Tags: c#, sql, sql-injection

```
string sqlconf = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sqlconstr"].ConnectionString;
string pathconf = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["expath"].ToString();
string sql = "select userid,logdate from Devicelogs_1_2015 where convert(varchar(10),LogDate,103) between '@fdate' and '@tdate';";

StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(pathconf);
SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(sqlconf);
SqlCommand sqlcom = new SqlCommand(sql, sqlcon);

sqlcom.Parameters.Add("@fdate", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
sqlcom.Parameters.Add("@tdate", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = dateTimePicker2.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");

sqlcon.Open();

using (sqlcon)
{
    using (SqlDataReader sqldr = sqlcom.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (sqldr.Read())
        {
            string userid1 = sqldr.GetString(0);
            DateTime logdate1 = sqldr.GetDateTime(1);

            sw.WriteLine("{0},{1}", userid1, logdate1.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
        }

        sw.Close();
        sqldr.Close();
    }

    sqlcon.Close();
    MessageBox.Show("File Exported Successfully");
    Close();
}
```

Comment: What is the problem? You haven't explained what the problem is and the question title is unclear.

Comment: dont store dates as strings  if you want them to act like dates.  to store just the date without the time element, use `xxxDbType.Date` and pass `dateTimePicker1.Value.Date`.  How any given DB stores dates is an *implementation detail*

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure exactly what you are asking but I do see these errors.

1. You should use the native types in your parameterized queries and not convert everything to string.
2. If you were using strings do not enclose the parameter in sql in quotes/ticks. However because these are actually date or datetime types you should not even be passing strings to begin with.
3. Wrap your disposable objects at the point you create them with using blocks

I have modified the code but only included the changed parts.

```
string sql = "select userid,logdate from Devicelogs_1_2015 where LogDate between @fdate and @tdate";

using(SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(sqlconf))
using(SqlCommand sqlcom = new SqlCommand(sql, sqlcon))
{
    sqlcom.Parameters.Add("@fdate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = dateTimePicker1.Value.Date;
    sqlcom.Parameters.Add("@tdate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = dateTimePicker2.Value.Date;

    sqlcon.open();
    // rest of the code that executes the query etc.
}
```

Note that if `LogDate` is a type that includes the time and you want to omit that you could cast it to a `Date`.

```
where cast(LogDate as date) between @fdate and @tdate
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're writing a query to use with parameters, you don't need to quote the strings.

```
string sql = "select userid,logdate from Devicelogs_1_2015 where convert(varchar(10),LogDate,103) between '@fdate' and '@tdate';";
```

should become:

```
string sql = "select userid,logdate from Devicelogs_1_2015 where convert(varchar(10),LogDate,103) between @fdate and @tdate;";
```

This should fix your issue